# Lectura y manipulación de ficheros en C

Tags: c

Os pongo en situación. Necesito hacer un programa en el que usuario elige un continente, después leerá el fichero del continente elegido y preguntará la capital de un país de ese continente. Por ahora me he centrado en Europa ya que una vez resuelto esto será casi idéntico en todos los demás continentes. El contenido del fichero es el siguiente:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/55ff8e57ccea63789a0d3d238d3c12df.png]

La primera línea es el Pais y la segunda la capital y así sucesivamente. Entonces, a mi no se me da muy bien esto. Seguramente sea una tonteria o he etendido yo mal la teoria. El código se ejecuta pero lee el fichero de una forma extraña. Os dejo aquí el código, gracias de ante mano!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 33
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N]);
//int Asia();
FILE *eu;
FILE *as;

int main()
{
    int p1, salir;
    char EuropaP[N][N];
    char EuropaC[N][N];
    while(salir != 0)
    {
        printf("-----MENU PRINCIPAL-----\n");
        printf("Elige un continente\n\n");
        printf("1. Europa\n");
        printf("2. Asia\n");
        printf("\nEscribe 0 para salir");
        printf("\nSeleccion: ");
        scanf("%d", &p1);
        if (p1 == 1)
        {
            Europa(EuropaP, EuropaC);
        }
        else if (p1 == 2)
        {
            //Asia();
        }
        else
            fclose(eu);
            //fclose(as);
        break;

    }
    return 0;
}
int Europa(char EuropaP[N][N], char EuropaC[N][N])
{
    int vida, c, i;
    eu = fopen("Europa.txt", "r");
    if (eu == NULL){
        printf("No se ha abierto correctamente el fichero");
    }
    else
        for(i=0; i<33; i++)
        {
            fscanf(eu, "%s\n%s", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
        }
    for(c=0; c<33; c++)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s", EuropaP[c], EuropaC[c]);
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Sólo necesito resolver el problema de lectura de fichero, el tema de las preguntas me encargo yo.

Ejenmplo de ejecución:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/uLCqV2l.png]

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que lo abre binario? Hasta donde me da la memoria, para eso deberíás haber añadido en el modo de apertura la opción `b` (sería `rb` para lectura binaria) y claramente no lo haces.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo en el hilo. Perdona la confusion

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en la forma como has escrito los datos en el archivo.

Es decir, si tenemos los siguientes datos en el archivo `Europa.txt`:

```
Francia
Paris
Alemania
Berlin
```

Y luego usas la función `fscanf` de esta manera:

```
fscanf(eu, "%s %s", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
```

No se almacenará en las matrices los datos de forma adecuada.

**¿Por qué no?**

Por qué en el formato le has especificado lo siguiente: `%s %s` y esto indica a la función `fscanf` que debe leer dos cadenas en una misma línea en la cual debe estar separado por un espacio, de lo contrario, esta función leerá los datos de forma incorrecta y por esa razón te imprime en pantalla caracteres extraños.

**Solución:** Necesitas agregar en una misma línea el país y el capital (separado por un espacio).

Por ejemplo:

```
//Así debe quedar la información en tu archivo Europa.txt:
Alemania Berlin
Francia Paris
//etc...
```

De este modo al invocar la función `fscanf` leerá dos cadenas y la guardará en los buffers (en este caso serían en las matrices) correspondiente.

**Observaciones:**

**1.** La función `Europa` debe retornar un valor, de lo contrario, debería ser definido como `void`.

**2.** A este bloque de código le falta las llaves de apertura y cierre:

```
    else
        for(i=0; i<33; i++)
        {
            fscanf(eu, "%s\n%s", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
        }
    for(c=0; c<33; c++)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s", EuropaP[c], EuropaC[c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Debería ser de esta forma:

```
else
{
     for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
         fscanf(eu, "%s %s", EuropaP[i], EuropaC[i]);
    }
    for(c=0; c<N; c++)
    {
        printf("%s\n%s", EuropaP[c], EuropaC[c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

En algunas ocasiones por no cerrar las llaves puede ocasionar errores lógicos (un suceso inesperado para el programador), así que mucho cuidado.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! De todas maneras, he dejado de usar fscanf y ahora estoy usando fgets que es mucho mas sencillo y práctico. El error de lectura del fichero era por la ausencia de un return 0 en el "if" al comprobar la apertura del fichero. Por si acaso, cambié la dirección del fichero. Y ahora todo funciona como debería.